# Custom keyboard layout not working in Mail

Tags: keyboard, mail.app, ukelele

I use [Ukelele](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?item_id=ukelele) to make a custom keyboard layout. In most (non-Apple) programs this works fine (iTerm, Sublime Text, Adium). In Mail and Calendar it is currently not working, although I believe it worked in the past. Selecting the input source doesn't do anything and leaves the previous one ticked. Both 10.9 and 10.11 seem to have this issue. I've tried [deleting the cache](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203221):

```
sudo rm /System/Library/Caches/com.apple.IntlDataCache*
sudo rm /var/folders/*/*/-Caches-/com.apple.IntlDataCache*
```

This did not help. Is there any reason for Mail (or Apple apps) not to accept custom keyboard layouts?

Comment: Does it work in other apple apps like TextEdit, Safari, Pages, Message?

Comment: Another good place to ask is the Ukelele group:   https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/ukelele-users

Comment: I've just seen Safari working. Feel 80% sure Mail worked in the past.